# Learning the Theory Behind Programming

Tags: programming-languages, theory

I'm interested in books that would introduce / explain the theory behind programming and programming languages. My logic is that by truly understanding the theory behind programming it will only take a few weeks to pick up new languages and implement some simple software.

As far as the type of books I'm looking for they would be similar to SICP.

I've done some research on this site and also on stack overflow. I know there are some large threads about books which discuss software architecture but I'm looking for information specific to programming. I have an okay understanding of Python which I've received from an into CS class on programming but I need to advance my knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: Despite the fact that there are some (admittedly very good) historical threads about books on SO, book recommendation questions are now generally considered off-topic.

Comment: That said, try studying lambda calculus, if you really want the Grand Unified Theory of programming. There isn't really any "secret decoder ring;" programming is a blissfully pragmatic profession. You learn best by doing.

Comment: Are you asking about theory of "How to do good programming?" or theory of "How programming languages work (inside the box)?"

Comment: While certain types of book recommendation questions are [on-topic here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic), this question is a bit too broad to be one of those. If there was a specific niche topic about programming where someone could supply you would *the* canonical book for it, that'd be something that could work here.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Disagree. There is a well-defined theory of programming languages, with well-defined books in the field.

Answer (score 7):

I took a course called Programming Language Concepts, which had two facets. The first was an overview of a number of different programming paradigms - functional, logic, object-oriented - which were taught using Scheme and Standard ML, Prolog, and Ruby when I took the course. The second facet of the course was about syntax, semantics, compilation, interpretation, and language features.

The textbook we used, which I thought was very well done, was [Programming Language Pragmatics by Michael Scott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123745144). This book covers both sides of the course very well. You can't use it to learn a language well, but it discusses topics including parsing, interpretation and compilation, grammars, scope, binding, data representation, control flow, garbage collection, and quite a bit more. It does these through discussions of Perl, C++, Java, C#, Prolog, Ruby, and a few other languages.

If you are more interested in learning new paradigms and languages without so much of the theory behind languages, another option is [The Pragmatic Programmers' Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193435659X). This book covers Ruby, Io, Prolog, Scala, Erlang, Clojure, and Haskell, with sample projects and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks mate...You have given me the link to what i was looking for but unable to put in words on here. BTW, does this book cover both the facets you talked in the answer ?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, it does.